# Hybrid App IFRAME youtube embedding not working

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm using ionic framework and got the error of "This video contains content from Vevo. It is restricted from playback on certain sites. Watch yon YouTube".

To reproduce my problem technically, try to post below code into your hybrid app and see the result in the android phone.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/09R8_2nJtjg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: I have the same problem as well. Did you try https?

Answer (score 0):

If you doesn't white-list the domain that you access outside the application will be blocked for security reason . In the case of Intel xdk please add the domain name in white-list as https://*/*

[Click to view the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJLXo.png)